# OOP for CUDA and OpenCL integration

Tags: c++, cuda, opencl

Here's the problem: I'm developing a framework (CLCuda, not the most creative name out there) where the programmer instantiates one object, and depending on what the system supports (CUDA or AMD OpenCL), will use the corresponding methods, without having to change any line of code to that.

I have a abstract class named `CLCuda` (pure virtual methods, but could be just virtual), and the two classes that implement its methods are `CLCudaCUDA` and `CLCudaOPENCL`.

I wanted to have something like this: instantiate one object that will iniciatlizate CUDA or OpenCL, depending on what graphics card the user have, that can access the methods of the available platform (through the class `CLCudaCUDA` or `CLCudaOPENCL`).

I already coded the methods of `CLCudaOpenCL` and `CLCudaCUDA` (hard times doing that), so my problem is with OOP.

How could I structure my classes?

If anyone can help... thanks very much!

Comment: It is easier to read than the last version, but you still aren't asking an actual question here.

Comment: More concrete problem please!

Comment: Look into Rendering Engines, it's basically the same problem - OpenGL vs DirectX, simply adapt it to CUDA / OpenCL

Comment: @Guilherme: why are you building such an API ? OpenCL is not specific to AMD and already provides the abstraction you're trying to get :)

Comment: @Serious: Well, it's no secrete that CUDA works better on NVIDIA cards than OpenCL, and in AMD cards the only way of using GPGPU is through OpenCL. So the work for my graduation thesis is a framework that leverages the performance that CUDA can give, with the possibility of running the same code with no necessary changes on a AMD GPU. Until the last year I didn't even know what GPGPU means, but this is getting really fun. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to suggest a ["Factory" design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Presumably you have a method to determine which is supported on the current host, so you should leverage that in the implementation of your factory.

Comment: YES! I was thinking on something exactly like that! I found a helpfull example in C++ and gonna try this. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Good enough for an upvote or even an accepted answer?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know about the 'accepted answer', but I tried the upvote and 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'. Tottaly newbie here... :P